# How to Connect AWS ECS (ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService) Private IP to RDS Security Group Using CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

How to Connect ECS Private IP to RDS Security Group Using CDK?

I need a private ip of ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService (CDK Code).

I tried the following (Failed to resolve) :

```
    const auroraSecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'security-group', {
      vpc,
      allowAllOutbound: true,
      description: 'Security Group of Aurora PostgreSQL',
      securityGroupName: AURORA_SECURITY_GROUP_NAME
    });

    auroraSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.ipv4('my ecs private ip'), ec2.Port.tcp(DB_PORT), 'describe');
```

Comment: I would allow the subnets instead of specific ip addresses

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to allow specific ip address, you have to specify with cidr.

```
ec2.Peer.ipv4('1.2.3.4/32')
```

Allow the security group of the fargate service as a source to arurora seucirty group:

```
auroraSecurityGroup.connections.allowFrom(ecsService.service, Port.tcp(3306), 'Inbound');
```

In this instance, its assumed that the ecs service is defined as follows.

```
const service = new ecs.FargateService(this, 'Service', {
  cluster,
  taskDefinition,
  desiredCount: 5,
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am wondering how to get cidr from CDK Fargate Service.

Comment: First of all i dont know how to get the cidr since i am new to CDK. But i think the most flexible solution for you to configure the `auroraSecurityGroup` to allow traffic from the security group of the ecs service. for that you should configure `EcsSecurity` group as the source in the `auroraSecurityGroup `

Comment: With regards to the CIDR block, you can get that from the inteface method [`vpcCidrBlock`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.IVpc.html#vpccidrblock) i.e. `vpc = new ec2.Vpc(...); vpc.vpcCidrBlock`.

Comment: Allowing the service worked great for me.  I had seen other examples where they add a security new security group to a `FargateService` using `FargateService.connections.addSecurityGroup` and then call `allowFrom` on that new security group, but that didn't work for me.   Using `allowFrom` on the service directly as shown here worked.

Comment: How to get `ecsService.service` mentioned in here? Is it referring to a cdk stackname.service?

Comment: @SomnathPawar if the ecs service is defined in cdk in a variable name `ecsService`, then the underlying service should be accessible via `ecsService.service`.